# Why use a compile_pattern for binary:replace?

Tags: performance, erlang

Is there any documentation that states why one should use a `compile_pattern/1` result as the pattern for `binary:replace/4` to search for?

I suspect it's for performance reasons but I can't find anything official that states as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know of any documentation that explicitly states it either, but yes, it's for performance reasons. If you pass a non-compiled pattern to the calls in the `binary` module, they will compile the pattern and then use it. This means that for a single use, compiling first doesn't really matter since the call will compile it anyway. But if you're performing multiple matches or replacements using the same pattern, it makes sense to compile it once up front and then pass the compiled pattern to each of the calls.

Comment: As I suspected re: the reason why. Thanks!